# What does [propName: string]: any; mean in typescript

Tags: typescript

What does this piece of code mean  `[propName: string]: any;` What concept is implemented here.I have heard one guy telling to me as this is indexers.Is it true.If so What is it.

```
interface SquareConfig {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
  [propName: string]: any;
}
```

Whay does  [propName: string]: any; Is it an array of string names that can be declared there

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: Please, do not edit the question in a way that it invalidates existing answer. It is considered very impolite to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry .I was having trouble understanding this.now got it

Answer (score 4):

If you declare like that for any of the component props interface then that component will accept anything as a prop i.e., you can pass any propName for that component.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Is it an array of string names that can be declared there.What does [] mean inside an interface.

Comment: @somanraj no, it's not an array of string names. It's what this answer (and the docs I linked above) says it is, a way of saying "any prop name".

Comment: @jonrsharpe so it meas "any property name that is a string"

Comment: @jonrsharpe and that propertyname can have any type

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks I was confused with the word prop

Answer (score -1):

[It doesn't mean anything, it is not syntactically legal.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHAcgQwLYFMYF4YDkBA3AFCkDaiy62AXDNAgJZgDmAug2mAJ7FA):

```
'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
',' expected.
';' expected.
```

Comment: Put curly braces around it, and try again.

Comment: @Jorg W Mittag. what are you telling it is in used inside an interface.Can you please help me understand this

Comment: @Evert: Please, look at the timeline. At the time I wrote my answer, the code in the question was completely different. I cannot predict the future, unfortunately, so I can only answer the question as it stands at the time I write the answer, I cannot answer the question as it will be changed in the future.

Comment: @JörgWMittag based on the _original_ question, my comment stands. You were either missing curly braces, but I suspect you were just missing empathy for OP. I left my comment before the edit.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am extremely sorry and wont do that in future

Comment: @Evert: I don't understand what you mean by "you were missing curly braces". I simply took the code from the question verbatim without modifications. Yes, of course, if I use different code, then the answer is different, but if I am answering a question about a *very specific* piece of code, then I should use *that very specific piece of code* and not some other piece of code in my answer, no?

Comment: If you used typescript for any amount of time, it would not have been difficult to recognize the snippet was taken from within an object type. Yes, by itself it's syntactically incorrect. Either you completely missed this (plausable), you barely used typescript (just don't answer next time), or you knew when writing your answer it wasn't going to be helpful (hence the empathy comment). I hope it was one of the first two.

Comment: If your answer was legitimately based on you not recognizing the syntax, perhaps it would have been better to leave this as a comment instead of an answer.